# Node Js PDF Phantom ENOENT

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, html-pdf

I have a node js server that generates a pdf - from an html body - with no problema installed locally in my PC (Windows) but when I installed in a remote server (Linux) get this error:

App 3111574 output: { Error: spawn /home/smorenoc/public_html/Casos/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe ENOENT
App 3111574 output:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
App 3111574 output:     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
App 3111574 output:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
App 3111574 output:   errno: 'ENOENT',
App 3111574 output:   code: 'ENOENT',
App 3111574 output:   syscall:
App 3111574 output:    'spawn /home/smorenoc/public_html/Casos/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe',
App 3111574 output:   path:
App 3111574 output:    '/home/smorenoc/public_html/Casos/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe',
App 3111574 output:   spawnargs:
App 3111574 output:    [ '/home/smorenoc/public_html/Casos/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/scripts/pdf_a4_portrait.js' ] }

/public_html/Casos/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs.exe is actually present in the server but seems not finding it

I don´t have access to terminal in server, I´m installing it trought cpanel.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add the scripts to the Dockerfile:
RUN apk add fontconfig ttf-dejavu
RUN apk add --no-cache curl &&
cd /tmp && curl -Ls https://github.com/dustinblackman/phantomized/releases/download/2.1.1/dockerized-phantomjs.tar.gz | tar xz &&
cp -R lib lib64 / &&
cp -R usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib &&
cp -R usr/share /usr/share &&
cp -R etc/fonts /etc &&
apk del curl

I did it and it works well. (node:12.20-alpine3.12)
```